# why does edititext control not show border of box?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I updated the sdk library from 2.1 to 4.1 and now the edittext control does not show the box border.  All it shows is a light blue line at the bottom of the control when it has focus.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is by design. It is the new look for `EditText` widgets using the Holo theme for Android 4.0 and above.

Comment: Do u have to set the background then to make the control look clear?  At the moment it is hard to see the controls on the screen as the background is white.

Comment: Give it an `android:hint` attribute to make it stand out on the page, and inform the user what they should enter, or add a TextView near it as a label. You can change the background, but it will change the entire view background, for all view states.